# Waiting for Paypal Payment Notification ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, paypal-ipn

I am implementing an ASP.NET web app where the user will fill an application that spans over multiple steps/Pages, with previous/Next buttons on each page to navigate back and forth to each step.

On the second step/page, I have a paypal payment button, so the user can pay for the services they selected on the first page.

My requirements is to wait for the user to pay with paypal and get the notification that a payment was received then navigate to the next page automatically. The user should not be able to proceed without payment.

The paypal payment button opens a new window with paypal site where the user makes the payment.

I looked at Paypal IPN (Instant Payment Notification), Paypal can send the notification to a service on the back-end in the web app, but how can I forward the user to the next page once this notification is received, since this service is not tied directly to the page that the user has opened on his browser?

The one way I am thinking to do is to store the payment in some table with the userid and a unique code and have a javascript function with setInterval(checkPayment, 5000); so every 5 seconds, it calls a service to check if there was a payment and forward the user.

Is there any better solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Better solution is to **NOT** involve IPN in your checkout flow. As stated:

> Because IPN is not a real-time service, your checkout flow should not wait for the IPN message before it is allowed to complete.

REF: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/

Paypal has an extensive API that handles your flow - e.g

- [Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/)
- [REST](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/)